# Multiple conditions with boolean :

Tags: javascript, d3.js, boolean

I'm using React and d3 for my project, using React to render. The chart in question is a hierarchical Circle Packing, with depths from 0 to 2.

Now, I need to change the outside stroke of the bubble like so:

```
.attr("stroke", d =>
  d.depth === 2 && d.data.opp >= opp ?
  null :
  medium_col
)
```

This works fine, except for the fact that I obtain "medium_col" also for the nodes with `d.depth === 1` (I want to obtain null in that case, no matter the value of opp).

Recap:

- `if (d.depth === 2 && d.data.opp >= opp)` THEN the condition works fine;
- `if (d.depth === 1)` THEN I want the stroke to be null.

Can someone help me, please? If you can find a better title, feel free to propose an alternative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `d.depth === 1 || (d.depth === 2 && d.data.opp >= opp) ? null : medium_col`.

Comment: Even not require a parenthesis, the `&&` operator have priority on the `||` operator